# How to create a database that can be used by many users?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, multi-user

What I have to do: I have to create an application in C# that can add values in a database, search trough the database and so on.. This application will be on several  Pc's ( this is a project for work ) and will insert values to the same database ( we want to create this database on a PC that is always ON)
We have the permision to use Sql server enterprise 2008. 
I know that it's much, but I want to know how to create the database to be used not just in the main PC so everyone can insert data in it if they use the app, I think it's called multi user database..
If you could give me some ideas and explanations it would help me a lot.. I read a few tutorials but I couldn't understand how can I connect to a database if it is not in my Pc.. everything is blurry in my head.

Comment: This is a very broad question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so, your database actually only needs one user (possibly also known as a schema, depending on your database), unless you want to limit who can do what.

Then, you need to configure your database to allow remote connections.

Once that's done, you'll be able to get something called a "connection string", which can be used in your application to open a connection to the database.

Once the connection is open, you can use SQL to read/write/edit the database.

If multiple users are going to be doing this simultaneously, you will need to look into things like row locking, transactions, and isolation modes.

I hope that helps your research get started

Comment: Schema, database & user are a bit more confusing. Schema & user are not always the same sometimes schema and database are the same - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems#Databases_vs_schemas_.28terminology.29 Prior to SQL Server 2005 schema & user were synonymous, from then they were not.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i have not well understood the question, but it seems like you just need to develop a plain client application that interfaces with a server (that wraps your DBMS)

there are billions ways to achieve this. Basically (but very basically) you have to create a "presentation layer" that deals directly with the user and, on the other side, pass data to a "service layer" that does some optional logic and converts input/output data in a format that can be sent across the network. Th server interact with multiple instances of these clients, reconverts data into objects and store them in your DB using a middleware that can "talk" in sql language. If you want to make your development process rapid there are a lot of tools (just to say NHibernate that simplifies the interaction between Db and the rest of application) but it's a wide argument and can't be exausted in just SO answer